# How to Show Launcher in advance before all android service is ready

Tags: android, launcher

I want to start the launcher as early as possible. When I put the function "`ActivityManagerService.self().systemReady`"  in `Systemserver.java` ahead. This only make the animated splash stop to moving  earlier and keep last frame for longer time.

Comment: Move your code to a background thread, that doesn't block the main thread.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Thanks, My attention is to speed up the boot time of android. I am trying to start the launcher before all the servicse are ready or remove some service. Hope some experts can help me.